# Cookies.JS how to remember many changes

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to save some changes in cookies, but it's not working.
I'm using https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie plugin.

My code:

```
var ctr = $(this).attr('data-contrast-type');

    if ( ctr === 'normal' ) {
        Cookies.set(function(){
            $('body').attr('class', '');
            $('.logo img').attr('src', 'img/logo.png');
            $('.listing-cta > li a img').attr('src', 'img/logo.png');
            $('body .sec1 .inner > img').attr('src', 'img/pic1.png');
        });
    }
```

Is this a good way to do this?
I have no errors in console.
Everything is attached to click event and i have 3 states (normal, high, higher).

Comment: From [this page](https://github.com/ScottHamper/Cookies) I'm seeing `Cookies.set(key, value)`. I don't know that library but `you` are the problem

Comment: Coming to your question about `remembering changes`... You may use an array as a `stack` of values, then serialize it to JSON before storing as string

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies,

```
document.cookie = "mycookie=DataToSaveHere"
```

or you can use too local Storage for save data in your browser

```
localStorage.setItem('mydata', 'YourDataSaveHere');
```

For get the data cookie ->

```
function getCookie(name)
{
    var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
      var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
      return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
}
```

For get the data localStorage ->

```
localStorage.getItem('mydata');
```